# На пути к .NET Core - пожалуйста, помогите Stack Exchange бесплатно протестировать EF Core!

Tags: обсуждение, тестирование

Stack Overflow многие вещи переносят на .NET Core. На этом сложном пути приходится заменять много легаси .NET кода.

[Сейчас есть возможность выкатить некоторые вещи, над которыми работали. Сегодня это Entity Framework Core](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316278/260198).

Десять лет назад Stack Overflow был написан поверх Linq-2-SQL. Он работал вполне сносно, но имел проблемы с масштабированием. Позднее критические элементы были заменены с использованием самопиской библиотеки Dapper. Но многие части (в основном, Insert'ы) остались на Linq-2-SQL. До сегодняшнего дня.

Только что был выкачен огромный кусок по миграции с Linq-2-SQL на EF Core на [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com) и [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com). Если всё пройдёт хорошо, Stack Overflow частично получит это же обновление чуть позднее сегодня.

<sub>Отвечая спрашивающим: Dapper никуда не делся. Dapper не был выпилен. Часть кода также была переведена на Dapper, а не EF Core.</sub>

### SE нужна помощь

Изменения коснулись вопросов/ответов, пользователей и многих других "основных" части Q&A. SE просит вас не создавать кучу тестовых постов на мете, но **если вы встретите что-то странное, сообщите об этом!** Вы, вероятно, не сумасшедшие, это всё SE (¬‿¬). Если что-то выглядит необычно, задайте новый вопрос на MSE и пинганите Ника лично в Twitter ([@Nick_Craver](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver)) или Stack Overflow чате.

Наибольшие опасения по поводу этих изменений - вероятность попадания плохих данных в БД, поэтому, несмотря на интенсивное тестирование, команда по-прежнему уделяет особое внимание такому важному и критическому изменению.

Спасибо за помощь. Если у вас есть вопросы, Ник постарается ответить!

---

**Обновление 1 (2018-10-03 19:00 UTC)**: выкатили сие дело на 9 серверах Stack Overflow и продолжают наблюдать за ситуацией.

Comment: Я нечасто тестирую свой код, но если я делаю это, то я делаю это в production.

Comment: @PashaPash Ирония по поводу методов разработки SE?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov нет, TiP - это вполне существующая методология https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seliot/2011/04/25/i-dont-always-test-my-code-but-when-i-do-i-do-it-in-production/ и https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seliot/2011/06/07/testing-in-production-tip-it-really-happensexamples-from-facebook-amazon-google-and-microsoft/

Comment: я не совсем понял, это какой-то перевод или что?

Comment: @Grundy там вторым предложением ссылка на оригинал...

Comment: @Suvitruf, по тексту вопроса просто непонятно, что это оригинал, а не просто какой-то вопрос :-)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо :D