# Неучтенный плюс за ответ на вопрос

Tags: дефект, репутация, уведомления

Ответ на вопрос: [о веб-программировании в будущем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/889218/236980)

Непонятно сколько плюсов поставлено: то ли 2, то ли 1.

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Последние пару часов лагает доставка событии в индикатор в верхнем баре.

Comment: Вчера сайт лежал некоторое время, возможно, это связанные явления

Comment: Задержки подобные бывают, обычно минут на 15, но я думаю, что [в связи с этой темой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7907/213987) в ближайшие дни будут более активно проводить различные работы и поэтому будет сильнее лихорадить сайт.

Comment: Нагавнякали опять https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316336/260198

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выкатили новый функционал [Reputation notifications seem to be broken again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316336/260198) с багами:

> We deployed some massive changes that we knew were risky but deployed
>   carefully and up until the last build of the last application they
>   looked awesome. In a "I wish more things would break so I don't think
>   I'm crazy" level of awesome.
>
> Then we built stackexchange.com (the app we considered the least
>   likely to break anything). That's when **shit hit the fan**. Queues shot
>   up. Alarms went off. Queries slowed down. Our SQL Servers slammed
>   against 20Gb network throughput limits. HTTP requests piled up. We
>   bounced between offline and unstable for 20 minutes. Then it went
>   downhill from there.

Связано с переделкой компонентов: [На пути к .NET Core - пожалуйста, помогите Stack Exchange бесплатно протестировать EF Core!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8056/15479)