# Все сайты сети тормозят

Tags: дефект

Открываются очень медленно из-за долгой загрузки самой страницы, остальные файлы (стили, скрипты) отдаются быстро. Видно даже, как хром рендерит страницу частями.

Скринвидео: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4Wq4/ECYyKg9BS
При просмотре стоит обратить внимание на скроллбар.

PS: [Этот вопрос на метамете.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/316380/309650)

Comment: На моей машине ничего не тормозит (С)

Comment: Второй вечер такое, причем вчера вылетали ошибки иногда при обновлении страницы, походу стэк слегка ложится по вечерам=)

Comment: @AK, уже починили.

Comment: А в чем смысл постить такие дефекты на руМете? Ещё и будучи модератором.

Comment: @alexolut, я решил, что на метамете уже кто-нибудь запостил, но при такой скорости открытия сайтов там вряд ли можно что-то найти. А тут хоть перевод ответа можно будет почитать. Особенно интересна техническая часть, если это как-то [с переходом на .net core](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8056/178988) связано. А то тот перевод есть, про баги тоже надо :)

Comment: @Qwertiy отдельного треда не видел. Но из-за криворукости у них там из-за перехода на EF нагрузка на сеть выросла при взаимодействие с SQL серверами. Частично проблема из-за этого.

Comment: Вообще, в твитере они пишут, если что-то не так https://twitter.com/StackStatus. Обычно проблемы связаны с апдейтами чего-либо.

Comment: @Suvitruf, похоже, оно: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SogU.png, так что причину я примерно угадал. А вот подробностей бы всё же хотелось.

Comment: @Qwertiy спросите на MSE, может и технических подробностей подкинут.

Comment: @AK, +скринвидео.

Comment: @Suvitruf, спросил.