# Возможные баги из-за перехода на .NET Core

Tags: обсуждение

Я уже ранее писал, что [SO постепенно на .NET Core переходят](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8056/15479). Недавно они в мастер снова выкатили много нового кода, что вылилось в баги. К примеру:

- ["Edit Approved" links are showing as plain text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323136/260198).
- [Broken bounty post notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323242/260198).

Не знаю, почему нигде анонса не было или ещё чего. В ближайшие дни возможно проявятся и другие баги.

Просто держу в курсе.

Comment: [дефект] - Метка для вопросов-уведомлений разработчиков сайта об ошибках. //// А тут вроде как надо наоборот, уведомление участников об ошибках ... [ткефед] что ли

Comment: @älёxölüt на MSE что-нить такое есть?

Comment: Сомневаюсь. По сути, любые изменения могут приводить к багам. А в случае серьёзных изменений заводят какой-то пост с меткой [featured], [важное] в местной интерпретации. Так что всё же [дефект] тут не совсем уместна, так как пост не описывает какой-то конкретный дефект, а просто обобщает возможные причины некоторых уже известных.

Comment: @älёxölüt вообще, это что-то типо "объявление" или типо того тогда.

Comment: [Угу](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/announcements). Дословный перевод.

Comment: Кстати, вместо крестика теперь ссылка "Удалить" для комментариев.

Comment: @älёxölüt ага. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323295/260198

Comment: Но поведение ещё [неконсистентно](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312830/flag-and-upvote-buttons-for-comments-are-now-always-visible) с флагами и апвоутом.