# Слетел перевод в выборе вариантов тревоги

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, тревоги

Только что заметил, что слетел перевод в меню тревог, ещё вечером всё было нормально:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм, у меня на русском о_О

Comment: Тем более интересно. Проверил ещё раз на другом сообщении, слетел.

Comment: Только в двух местах: *непонятна суть вопроса* и *необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ*, на Мета, та же история

Comment: Странно, у меня буквально минут 10 - 20 назад было на русском, а теперь тоже слетело.

Comment: У меня что-то вообще странно. Бывает при обновлении пол сайта без перевода. То есть то нет.

Comment: Возможно с этим связано https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8660/15479.

Comment: Сейчас вроде бы не проявляется.

Comment: @älёxölüt опять появилось )=

Comment: @Suvitruf уже нормально :)

Comment: @älёxölüt что_тут_****_происходит.jpg?

Comment: Слетало сегодня опять, я тоже заметил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял, окончательно пофиксили: [The description for the "unclear what you are asking" and "primarily opinion-based" close reasons need translation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323448/260198).

И, опять же, баг связан с [переходом на .NET Core](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8660/15479) (: